# FileNotFoundError When file exists (when created in current script)

Tags: python, file-not-found

I am trying to create a secure (e.g., SSL/HTTPS) XML-RPC Client Server. The client-server part works perfectly when the required certificates are present on my system; however, when I try to **create** the certificates during execution, I receive a **FileNotFoundError** when opening the ssl-wrapped socket even though the certificates are clearly present (because the preceding function created them.)

Why is the FileNotFoundError given when the files are present? (If I simply close and restart the python script no error is produced when opening the socket and everything works with no issue whatsoever.)

I've searched elsewhere for solutions, but the best/closest answer I've found is, perhaps, "race conditions" between creating the certificates and opening them. However, I've tried adding "sleep" to alleviate the possibility of race conditions (as well as running each function individually via a user input menu) with the same error every time.

What I am missing?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import os
import threading
import ssl 
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer
import certs.gencert as gencert  # <---- My python module for generating certs

...

rootDomain = "mydomain"
CERTFILE = "certs/mydomain.cert"
KEYFILE = "certs/mydomain.key"

...

def listenNow(ipAdd, portNum, serverCert, serverKey):

    # Create XMLRPC Server, based on ipAdd/port received
    server = SimpleXMLRPCServer((ipAdd, portNum))

    # **THIS** is what causes the FileNotFoundError ONLY if
    # the certificates are created during THE SAME execution
    # of the program.
    server.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(server.socket,
                                    certfile=serverCert,
                                    keyfile=serverKey,
                                    do_handshake_on_connect=True,
                                    server_side=True)
    ...
    # Start server listening [forever]
    server.serve_forever()

...

# Verify Certificates are present; if not present,
# create new certificates
def verifyCerts():

    # If cert or key file not present, create new certs
    if not os.path.isfile(CERTFILE) or not os.path.isfile(KEYFILE):

        # NOTE: This [genert] will create certificates matching 
        # the file names listed in CERTFILE and KEYFILE at the top
        gencert.gencert(rootDomain)
        print("Certfile(s) NOT present; new certs created.")

    else:
        print("Certfiles Verified Present")


# Start a thread to run server connection as a daemon
def startServer(hostIP, serverPort):

    # Verify certificates present prior to starting server
    verifyCerts()

    # Now, start thread
    t = threading.Thread(name="ServerDaemon",
                         target=listenNow,
                         args=(hostIP,
                               serverPort,
                               CERTFILE,
                               KEYFILE
                               )
                         )
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    startServer("127.0.0.1", 12345)
    time.sleep(60)  # <--To allow me to connect w/client before closing
```

When I run the above, with NO certificates present, this is the error I receive:

```
$ python3 test.py
Certfile(s) NOT present; new certs created.
Exception in thread ServerDaemon:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "test.py", line 41, in listenNow
server_side=True)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 1069, in wrap_socket
ciphers=ciphers)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 691, in __init__
self._context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

When I simply re-run the script a second time (i.e., the cert files are already present when it starts, everything runs as expected with NO errors, and I can connect my client just fine.

```
$ python3 test.py
Certfiles Verified Present
```

What is preventing the ssl.wrap_socket function from seeing/accessing the files that were just created (and thus producing the FileNotFoundError exception)?

EDIT 1:
Thanks for the comments John Gordon. Here is a copy of gencert.py, courtesy of Atul Varm, found here https://gist.github.com/toolness/3073310

```
import os
import sys
import hashlib
import subprocess
import datetime

OPENSSL_CONFIG_TEMPLATE = """
prompt = no
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req
[ req_distinguished_name ]
C                      = US
ST                     = IL
L                      = Chicago
O                      = Toolness
OU                     = Experimental Software Authority
CN                     = %(domain)s
emailAddress           = varmaa@toolness.com
[ v3_req ]
# Extensions to add to a certificate request
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = %(domain)s
DNS.2 = *.%(domain)s
"""

MYDIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
OPENSSL = '/usr/bin/openssl'
KEY_SIZE = 1024
DAYS = 3650
CA_CERT = 'ca.cert'
CA_KEY = 'ca.key'

# Extra X509 args. Consider using e.g. ('-passin', 'pass:blah') if your
# CA password is 'blah'. For more information, see:
#
# http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html#PASS_PHRASE_ARGUMENTS
X509_EXTRA_ARGS = ()

def openssl(*args):
    cmdline = [OPENSSL] + list(args)
    subprocess.check_call(cmdline)

def gencert(domain, rootdir=MYDIR, keysize=KEY_SIZE, days=DAYS,
            ca_cert=CA_CERT, ca_key=CA_KEY):
    def dfile(ext):
        return os.path.join('domains', '%s.%s' % (domain, ext))

    os.chdir(rootdir)

    if not os.path.exists('domains'):
        os.mkdir('domains')

    if not os.path.exists(dfile('key')):
        openssl('genrsa', '-out', dfile('key'), str(keysize))

    # EDIT 3: mydomain.key gets output here during execution

    config = open(dfile('config'), 'w')
    config.write(OPENSSL_CONFIG_TEMPLATE % {'domain': domain})
    config.close()

    # EDIT 3: mydomain.config gets output here during execution

    openssl('req', '-new', '-key', dfile('key'), '-out', dfile('request'),
            '-config', dfile('config'))

    # EDIT 3: mydomain.request gets output here during execution    

    openssl('x509', '-req', '-days', str(days), '-in', dfile('request'),
            '-CA', ca_cert, '-CAkey', ca_key,
            '-set_serial',
            '0x%s' % hashlib.md5(domain + 
                                 str(datetime.datetime.now())).hexdigest(),
            '-out', dfile('cert'),
            '-extensions', 'v3_req', '-extfile', dfile('config'),
            *X509_EXTRA_ARGS)

    # EDIT 3: mydomain.cert gets output here during execution

    print "Done. The private key is at %s, the cert is at %s, and the " \
          "CA cert is at %s." % (dfile('key'), dfile('cert'), ca_cert)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print "usage: %s <domain-name>" % sys.argv[0]
        sys.exit(1)
    gencert(sys.argv[1])
```

EDIT 2:
Regarding John's comment, *"this might mean that those files are being created, but not in the directory [I] expect"*:

When I have the directory open in another window, I see the files pop up in the **correct** location during execution. In addition, when running the `test.py` script a second time with no changes, the files are identified as present in the correct (the same) location. This leads me to believe that file location is not the problem. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll keep looking.

EDIT 3: 
I stepped through the gencert.py program, and each of the files are correctly output at the right time during execution. I indicated when exactly they were output within the above file, labeled with "EDIT 3"

While gencert is paused awaiting my input (raw_input), I can open/view/edit the mentioned files in another program with no problem.

In addition, with the first test.py instance running (paused, waiting for user input, just after mydomain.cert appears), I can run a second instance of test.py in another terminal and it sees/uses the files just fine.

Within the first instance, however, if I continue the program it outputs "FileNotFoundError."

Comment: You haven't shown us the code for `gencert`, so it's possible that function just isn't doing what it's supposed to.  As a very simple check, try adding another `if not os.path.isfile(...)` call inside `verifyCerts()`, _after_ the call to `gencert()`.

Comment: Does `gencert()` _close_ the files after creating them?  If not, this could explain the behavior you're seeing -- the files might not actually get written to disk until the program exists.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @John 
Here is a link to the gencert function I used, which I will review more closely and see if it solves my problem:
https://gist.github.com/toolness/3073310

Comment: @john You are correct, the problem must be with `gencert()`, as I added the other `if not os.path.isfile()` after the call to `gencer()` and the files are still not present at that point.

Comment: I see that `gencert()` contains a call to `os.chdir()`.  Since you're using _relative paths_ for `CERTFILE` and `KEYFILE`, it might be that those files _are_ created, but not in the directory you expect.

Comment: Since you have the ability to monitor the file creation from a separate window, can you try pausing the program (by adding `raw_input()` calls) at various points after calling `gencert()`, to see when the files actually get created?

Comment: @JohnGordon -- Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem contained in the above stems from the use of `os.chdir(rootdir)` as suggested by John; however, the specifics are slightly different than the created files being in the wrong location. The problem is the current working directory (cwd) of the running program being changed by `gencert()`. Here are the specifics:

1. The program is started with `test.py`, which calls `verifyCerts()`. At this point the program is running in the current directory of whichever folder `test.py` is running inside of. Use `os.getcwd()` to find the current directory at this point. In this case (as an example), it is running in:

   `/home/name/testfolder/`
2. Next, `os.path.isfile()` looks for the files "certs/mydomain.cert" and "certs/mydomain.key"; based on the file path above [e.g., the cwd], it is looking for the following files:

   `/home/name/testfolder/certs/mydomain.cert`
   `/home/name/testfolder/certs/mydomain.key`
3. The above files are not present, so the program executes `gencert.gencert(rootDomain)` which **correctly** creates both files as expected in the exact locations mentioned above in number 2.
4. **The problem** is indeed the `os.chdir()` call: When `gencert()` executes, it uses `os.chdir()` to change the cwd to "rootdir," which is `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`, which is the directory of the current file (gencert.py). Since this file is located a folder deeper, the new cwd becomes:

   `/home/name/testfolder/certs/`
5. When `gencert()` finishes execution and the control returns to `test.py`, the cwd never changes again; the cwd remains as `/home/name/testfolder/certs/` even when execution returns to `test.py`.
6. Later, when `ssl.wrap_socket()` tries to find the serverCert and serverKey, it looks for "certs/mydomain.cert" and "certs/mydomain.key" **in the cwd**, so here is the full path of what it is looking for:

   `/home/name/testfolder/certs/certs/mydomain.cert`
   `/home/name/testfolder/certs/certs/mydomain.key`
7. These two files are **NOT** present, so the program correctly returns "FileNotFoundError".

**Solution**

A) Move the "gencert.py" file to the same directory as "test.py"

B) At the beginning of "gencert.py" add `cwd = os.getcwd()` to record the original cwd of the program; then, at the very end, add `os.chdir(cwd)` to change back to the original cwd before ending and giving control back to the calling program.

I went with option 'B', and my program now works flawlessly. I appreciate the assistance from John Gordon to point me toward finding the source of my problem.